# replace Add with Get on django admin site

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model that I don't want user to manually add/delete objects. Instead, I want to have some Get button that once clicked, it executes some code and automatically update the database. 
  I was able to do similar things via adding my own admin action. However, adding an admin action by default means you have to have at least one object for your model, you select that object and performs some action. 
  I want be able to perform my customized action on an empty model (if I can replace the Add button with a Get button on the index page, it will be perfect). Is there a way to do so? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could override the add_view method of the django admin model and do whatever you felt like having that view do if you wanted. Poke around through the ModelAdmin code and you can see what it does by default

you could also take a look at this project: https://github.com/imtapps/django-admin-ext and see an example of how to register your own urls for an admin... so you could make your view something like admin/myproject/myapp/model/get  and have it do what you'd like...

Answer (score 0):

1. You can prevent users from adding new objects by removing the "Can add ModelName" permission from that user. If they're a superuser that won't actually stop them from doing that, however.
2. Admin actions are designed to be run on specific instances of the model; if that's not what your code is doing you probably shouldn't go that particular route. You can [override the admin template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) for your model and add a new button or link to your custom view. You could also remove the Add button entirely by eliminating it from your template, but I'd recommend using permissions instead.